# How to use rmt command in tcl script? (Expectk)

Tags: shell, tcl, expect

I am trying to create a tcl script that uses Expectk and the rmt command. I can spawn an rmt process and get the correct process ID, but no send command I use works. I noticed from the man page that the normal send command is defined for a different purpose, so I should be using exp_send.

Here is the script. All I want to do is get the status of the tape drive:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Restarts using wish in the command search path
exec expectk "$0" -- "$@"

set stored_id [spawn "rmt"]
exp_send -i $stored_id "O/dev/nst0\r"
exp_send -i $stored_id "S\r"
```

Edit: This is how you use the command from the command line normally:

```
$ rmt
O/dev/nst0
S
A0
^C
```

The "A0" is the response from the command, and ^C is me pressing Ctrl-C to exit the rmt command.

Comment: I'd suggest two things: 1. Replace `rmt` command in your script with `cat` and verify that it works. 2. See if piping data directly to `rmt` works.

Comment: You might have better luck using `autoexpect` and then hand-crafting the resulting script.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Belikoff How can I use `cat` in the script? I was not able to pipe data into `rmt` and have it work correctly. I tried this: `echo "O/dev/nst0" | echo "S" | rmt`, and I got an error being returned from the command. The command did execute at least, but it's not executing correctly. It returns `E9 Bad file descriptor` when it should be returning `A0`.

@glennjackman I tried using `autoexpect`, and it did generate a script, but I'm have the same issue where `rmt` gets spawned and then it just hangs like it's waiting for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AlexanderL.Belikoff put me on the right track.

I didn't really understand the man page for this command at all at first. The following seems to work to open up the device for reading and writing, and that it gets the status of the device. The status will automatically be put on the screen, but the "Got the status" part just means the command executed successfully.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Restarts using wish in the command search path
exec expectk "$0" -- "$@"

spawn "rmt"
exp_send "O/dev/nst0\r"
exp_send "O_RDRW\r"
expect "A0" {
    puts "Success!"
}

exp_send "S\r"
expect "A" {
    puts "Got the status"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending `\n\r` at the end of each command. The following kind of works for me (note, using raw `expect`):

```
spawn "rmt"

send "O/goo/bar\n\r"
    expect  "E22" {
    puts "Error!!!"
}
```

Comment: Turns out I wasn't seeing output because I didn't have an `expect` statement for `A0` and apparently because I was using the `-i` part. I will put my full script as an edit in my question, but your code here led me to it, so I'm going to accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: I decided to put my own answer and take it out of the question. I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, so please let me know.